# IBM data sci question about if/else in finding mean

Tags: python, mean

Your task is to complete the getNAvg function that computes a simple moving average for N days for the precipiation data, where N is a parameter. Your function should return a list of moving averages for the given data.

The formula for a k day moving average over a series -  0,2,3.... is:
=−1+−−,for i = k to m where  is the moving average

There's 2 questions I have on this code, see below - appreciate anyone's help to explain a little further of what's going.

Below is the code that solves the question:

```
def getNAvg(file,N):
    """
    file - File containting all the raw weather station data
    N - The number of days to compute the moving average over

    Return a list of containg the moving average of all data points
    """
    row = 0 # keep track of rows
    lastN = [] # keep track of last N points
    mean = [0] # running avg  

    with open(file,"r") as rawData: 
        for line in rawData:
            if (row == 0): # Ignore the headers
                row = row + 1
                continue

            line = line.strip('\n')
            lineData = float(line.split(',')[1])

            if (row<=N): 
                lastN.append(lineData)
                mean[0] = (lineData + mean[0]*(row-1))/row
            else:
                mean.append( mean[row - N -1]+ (lineData - lastN[0])/N)
                lastN = lastN[1:]
                lastN.append(lineData)

            row = row +1            
        return mean
```

- **Question 1**: why assign mean = [0] in this line?

```
mean = [0] # running avg
```

- **Question 2:** is on the if/else block - I'm kinda lost here on what's happening, not sure if anyone could provide an explanation that a newbie would get, but figured I'd ask since I didn't understand this part of the code.

```
            if (row<=N): 
                lastN.append(lineData)
                mean[0] = (lineData + mean[0]*(row-1))/row
            else:
                mean.append( mean[row - N -1]+ (lineData - lastN[0])/N)
                lastN = lastN[1:]
                lastN.append(lineData)

            row = row +1            
        return mean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it slightly less confusing to change this:

```
 if (row<=N): 
            lastN.append(lineData)
            mean[0] = (lineData + mean[0]*(row-1))/row
```

to this:

```
 if (row<=N): 
            lastN.append(lineData)
            mean[0] = sum(lastN)/len(lastN)
```

That more closely resembled how I would calculate the mean in any other circumstance since all that was happening in this block of code was the mean list was just being changed to the current average (mean) of lastN

Answer (score 2):

Imagine this is the file "weather-data.txt" you provide:

```
time, temperature
1, 20
2, 25
3, 30
4, 25
5, 30
```

Why does the file might look like this?

-> because from the function we can see the first row contains a header (#ignore the headers) and `lineData = float(line.split(',')[1])` splits the file by comma and takes the second column (which I call temperature in the file)

**First let's see the function in action with this specific file as an example**

call the function with this file above and let's check the result

```
file = "path/to/weather-data.txt"
print(getNAvg(file,3)
# [25.0, 26.666666666666668, 28.333333333333336]
```

What does the print show us?
It's a list of the moving average. First element in the output-list is the mean temperature for time 1-3, then second element is the mean for time 2-4 and third is the mean for time 3-5.

---

Now let's come to your questions:

**Question 1**

```
mean = [0] # running avg
print(mean)
#[0]
```

Will just initialize a list with one element -> a zero-value element.
This list will be used later in the if-else statement, to fill up with the moving averages we look for - we will get into details later.

**Question 2**

```
            if (row<=N): 
                lastN.append(lineData)
                mean[0] = (lineData + mean[0]*(row-1))/row
            else:
                mean.append( mean[row - N -1]+ (lineData - lastN[0])/N)
                lastN = lastN[1:]
                lastN.append(lineData)

            row = row +1            
        return mean
```

This is the interesting part of the function, let's go through it one by one

- remember: before we enter this if-else, we already skipped the header (`row=0`)
- 1. first line of data `row=1, lineData=20` => since `row<=3` we go through this part of the statement

```
lastN.append(lineData)
mean[0] = (lineData + mean[0]*(row-1))/row
```

that means

```
#lastN = [20]
#mean[0] = (20 + 0 * (1-1)) / 1 = [20]
```

- 2. second line of data `row=2, lineData=25` => still `row<=3` so we go through the part above again

```
#lastN = [20,25]
#mean[0] = (25 + 20 * (2-1)) / 2 = [22.5]
```

- 3. third line of data `row=3, lineData=30` => still `row<=3` so we go through the part above again

```
#lastN = [20,25,30]
#mean[0] = (30 + 22.5 * (3-1)) / 3 = [25]
```

Ok now **25** this is the first element of the result-list we saw in the beginning.

- 4. fourth line of data `row=4, lineData=25` => now `row>3` so we go trough the else part of the statement:

```
mean.append( mean[row - N -1]+ (lineData - lastN[0])/N)
lastN = lastN[1:]
lastN.append(lineData)
```

this means for our example

```
#mean.append( mean[4 -3 -1] + ((25 - 20) / 3)) = mean.append( mean[0] + 1.66666) => [25, 26.666666]
#lastN = [25,30] 
#lastN.append(lineData) => [25,30,25]
```

- 5. Fifth line of data `row=5, lineData=30` => similar to step 4.

```
# mean.append( mean[5 -3 -1] + ((30 - 25) / 3)) = mean.append( mean[1] + 1.66666) => [25, 26.666666, 28.333333]
#lastN = [30,25] 
#lastN.append(lineData) => [30,25,30]
```

**Now finally**

we see the result list is exactly what we saw before: [25, 26.666666, 28.333333] - the list of moving averages with N=3